# How to connect azure postgres from my microservice

Tags: java, postgresql, azure, spring-boot

I have a microservice to read data from json and to save in local postgres but now i want to use azure postgres instead of local DB. When i try to connect using application properties im getting timeout error. Is there anything im missing?

In my connection security i have enabled Allow access to Azure services, i have also added my ip address in firewall rule and my SSl setting is disabled.

My application properties file for local postgres, which is working fine

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MyDB
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
```

My application properties for azure postgres which is not working

```
spring.datasource.url : myapp.postgres.database.azure.com/test
spring.datasource.username: adminmyapp@myapp
spring.datasource.password: 123456
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
```

Is my application properties correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to mention the driver as well,

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://myapp.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/MyDB
```

Comment: i added..But im getting "The connection attempt failed"

Comment: im sure something is wrong , check database name url and everything

Comment: Thanks i will check! is this the right way to connect my microservice to azure postgres? as in using application properties file